# How to sync up server time with client in multiplayer game?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am creating a game in which I have to sync up server time with client. Game has multiple players there will be start time of the game and no. of rounds in a game and in how much time the game will get complete. I need to add countdown for each round in a game like if game is of 20 minutes and it contain 10 rounds so each round will be of 2 minutes(divide game time with game round).But the problem is I am not able to run countdown on client side based on server time.Please help how can i run countdown (Note:any player can login anytime if game start at 6:00am and player login at 6:05am so the count should start from the time remaining for the game it should sync up with server time on multiple machines and for multiple players ).Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/timesync
```

for time sync between server and clients.
But its about seconds. If your delay in minutes its about smth else